# Playing videos without launching Media Player? iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, video

How would I play videos on my app without launching the player.
So by just pressing a button, the video would play.

Sorry if not explained very well..

Like MadPad

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LADgRaq3g8I
```

Or is this just an array of images, like a animation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 Video Player rendered in a UIWebView could achieve this effect.

Comment: Thanks, Do you know if there is any limit on the video size or anything?

Comment: I believe html5 video doesn't work, check this http://sublimevideo.net/demo - I tested html5 video on my iPhone however the video doesn't play on the website, it launches the media player

Comment: It will launch on the media player on the iPhone but not on the iPad. I don't know about limits, however featured length movies are played this way.